# use subprocess in Python to use OpenSSL to print a PKCS7 certifcate to a file

Tags: python, pkcs#7

There is plenty of code for OpenSSL/UNIX for Encrypting/Decrypting cert files.
I would like to know if there is some code I can put into Python 3.5 that will print and create an output file of that information. Here is the OpenSSL command that works wonderfully:

```
OpenSSL> pkcs7 -inform DER -n CERT.RSA -out CERT.TXT -noout -print_certs -text
```

This converts the file so that I can easily read it. Try this for yourself in OpenSSL. I am not an expert in Python and I am trying to learn how to use my skills in Python for automation. Thank you for any input.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you to the ones that read my question. I figured it out. I hope that this helps someone.
PYTHON CODE:

```
subprocess.Popen(['openssl.exe', 'pkcs7', 'DER', '-in', InputFile, '-out', OutputFile,
    'print_certs', '-text'], stdout=None, stderr=None, shell=True)
```